# Why vscode's Command Palette can't show all command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some command like `cursorUndo` or `editor.action.insertCursorAbove` cannot be found in the command Palette. How can I find these command with in the command palette?

Answer (score 1):

Most everything under `editor.action.x` is for keyboard mappings and you won't find it in the command palette. Single action things like controlling the cursor are for keystrokes and not command palette, just the way the API in VS Code was built I guess.